# Saber el nombre de las columnas donde el valor sea true SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo puedo consultar si el producto `"15000332"` tiene `Lista_1` asi:

```
SELECT Lista_1 
FROM Producto
WHERE ID_Producto_SKU=15000332 AND Lista_1=true
```

Viene mi consulta, como puedo saber cuales columnas llamadas `"Lista_X"` tienen true, por ejemplo para el producto `33000339` solo tiene las lista 1,2,3,6,7,8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo único que quieres es una cadena que indica en cuales listas está como verdadero, puedes usar múltiples IIF() y concatenarlos.

```
SELECT ID_Producto_SKU,
    STUFF(CONCAT(
    IIF(Lista_1=1,',1', ''),
    IIF(Lista_2=1,',2', ''),
    IIF(Lista_3=1,',3', ''),
    IIF(Lista_4=1,',4', ''),
    IIF(Lista_5=1,',5', ''),
    IIF(Lista_6=1,',6', ''),
    IIF(Lista_7=1,',7', ''),
    IIF(Lista_8=1,',8', '')), 1, 1, '')
FROM Producto
WHERE ID_Producto_SKU=15000332;
```

Agregué una coma al inicio de cada valor y retiro la primer coma usando STUFF()